# Watch for file changes in Dart

Tags: dart

Is it possible to watch for file changes (deletion, creation, edit) in Dart, like in NodeJS?

I do not seem to be able to find an answer to this, is it possible that it will be implemented in the future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to take a look at [FileSystemEntity.watch()](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.9.0-15.0.dev/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/watch.html) method. However due to platform differences some platforms provide better support than others. In particular, on Windows you can only watch a Directory, and not just an individual file. On Linux you can watch Files or Directories but not recursively watch Directories. And MacOS supports all of the above.

There is also a [watcher](https://pub.dev/packages/watcher) package on Pub. This supports polling (periodically check if the file has changed) if the file system does not allow watching.

Comment: Thanks. I think you meant in Windows you can only watch a directory? Also do you think this will become cross-platform in the future like in NodeJS?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my typo. This is the same type of implementation that nodeJS already has. See the Caveats for NodeJS watch: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_caveats

Comment: watcher example here: https://github.com/dart-lang/watcher/tree/master/example