# Is there a way to watch for changes to files matching a glob in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-io

I'm trying to implement something similar to the [gulp.watch() function in gulp.js](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb), and watch for create/delete/changes to files matching a glob (i.e. '**/*.dart', 'tests/*.dart').

Is there a way to do this using the standard library, or a way to implement this using a package on pub?

Comment: this may be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050962

Comment: Thanks Gunther. Took a look at that but it only watched a single part with the option to watch recursively. It doesn't seem to handle matching the emitted events against a glob. Maybe I will try to write my own.

Comment: quiver.pattern has a `Glob` implementation, and an quiver.io library with some utilities, but nothing typing them together yet. If you want to contribute this watcher to Quiver, it'd be welcome.

Comment: Thanks Justin! I'll check out quiver!